# Uploading a form having an image file without refreshing the page

Tags: php, jquery, forms, upload

I want to post a form to the php script which process the form and add the data into database then send back the just uploaded form to the event handler of jquery. The form contains an image file in it.
My problem is that i am not getting the response back from php script to the event handler.

```
      $('#Form').on('submit',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();           
        $("#output").html('loading...');
        $("#Form").ajaxForm({
            target: '#output'
            };

        });
 <form action="post.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="Form">
        <textarea class="post" name="text" style="height:10; font-size:16px;">    </textarea>

        <input type="file" name="pic"  class="post_image"/>   
         <input type="submit" name="subp" id="postButton" value="post" class="post_button" />    
        </form> 

        <div id="output"></div>


          //post.php

    <?php
echo "hi";
    ?>
```

the problem is #output div is always showing "loading..." instead it should show "hi" returned by php script.

Answer (score 2):

You've to use iframe for this kind of functionality

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="post.php" target="imageUploaderFrame">
<label>Upload Image: </label><input type="file" name="profile_image" id="uploadProfileImage"/>
</form>

<iframe id="imageUploaderFrame" name="imageUploaderFrame" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

Comment: Even if i just want the "hi" output (not image) from php script in the #output div,its not responding, for which i dont think <iframe> is required.

Answer (score 0):

```
**you should fadeout div output when success your ajaxFrom**
$("#Form").ajaxForm(
{
  target: '#output',
  success: function() 
  { 
      $("#output").fadeOut(2000);
  } 
};
```